# ImportError: cannot import name social_auth_usersocialauth: Accessing Python social auth data in django via shell

Tags: python, django, sqlite, shell

I am getting log in data from twitter. In my sqlite database, following are the tables:

```
sqlite> .tables
auth_group                  django_content_type       
auth_group_permissions      django_migrations         
auth_permission             django_session            
auth_user                   social_auth_association   
auth_user_groups            social_auth_code          
auth_user_user_permissions  social_auth_nonce         
django_admin_log            social_auth_usersocialauth
```

My data is saved into `social_auth_usersocialauth` table. Query the table using sqlite3 shell gives me the data I fetched from the website.

```
1|twitter|xx|1|{"access_token": {"oauth_token_secret": "xx", "oauth_token": "xx", "x_auth_expires": "0", "user_id": "xx", "screen_name": "xx"}, "id": xx}
```

Now I want to display `oauth_token_secret` and `oauth_token` in my template.

I am trying to run following query from django shell to check whether I can fetch data or not. Since my app name is `social.apps.django_app.default` so I ran the following code:

```
>>> from social.apps.django_app.default.models import social_auth_usersocialauth
```

But it is giving

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
> ImportError: cannot import name social_auth_usersocialauth
> ```

trying another name, `twitter`, which is my app name, I got the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**@lerner:** You have to import table name correctly. Try to run this import statement in your python shell

```
from social.apps.django_app.default.models import UserSocialAuth
```

And hope you can now access your table contents by querying this table.

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely a problem in the model import

Is the model in the models.py file? If so does what you've written match ? Post the models.py file and the folder structure.

Is the app name actually social.apps.django_app...

Typically a django project is structured thus

Project name
- app name
--- models.py
- app name
...

References in django shell are then 
from appname.models import modelname

Django would then name the database table
Appname_modelname

Comment: No model is not in `models.py`. It's autmatically downloaded for python social auth.

Comment: It should be from ... import UserSocialAuth Refer here for models.py source https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py

Answer (score 0):

It's now `from social_django.models import UserSocialAuth`